# Problem with seeding data in pivot table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-seeding

I have a problem while attempting to seed my pivot table in database in Laravel. I get error

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'user_cuisines' doesn't exist
```

And my table name is actually user_cuisine, so it is like for some reason laravel doesn't show that table. I added in my relationships that user_cuisine is pivot table because of alphabet order. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

UserCuisineTableSeeder.php

```
<?php

use App\UserCuisine;
use App\UserProfile;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UserCuisineTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $cuisines = UserCuisine::all();

        UserProfile::all()->each(function ($userProfile) use ($cuisines) { 
            $userProfile->cuisines()->attach(
                $cuisines->random(rand(1, 12))->pluck('id')->toArray()
            ); 
        });
    }
}
```

DatabaseSeeder.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(WhitelabelTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(CitiesTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(UserTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(UserProfilePropertiesSeeder::class);
        $this->call(UserProfileTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(FieldTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(FieldValueTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(CuisineTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(LiteratureTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(MusicTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(SportTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(TvTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(UserCuisineTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(UserInterestTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

UserCuisine.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserCuisine extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    public function userProfiles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(UserProfile::class, 'user_cuisine');
    }
}
```

UserProfile.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

class UserProfile
{

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function cuisines()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(UserCuisine::class, 'user_cuisine');
    }
}
```

user_cuisine_table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUserCuisineTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_cuisine', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('cuisine_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('user_cuisine');
    }
}
```

cuisine_table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCuisineTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cuisine', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('cuisine');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel expect the table name to be `user_cuisines` but you named it `user_cuisine` without the "s"

You can fix that by changing  your migration or adding `protected $table = 'user_cuisine';` to your model.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserCuisine extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'user_cuisine';

}
```

As naming convention goes, I would recommend changing the table name

Comment: Okay, that is correct. But now I get error   You requested 6 items, but there are only 0 items available.

Comment: hello @rose, seems like a different issue on your random() function in your Seeder. Are you sure you have cuisines ? (you are asking for  up to 12)

Comment: Yes I see that, but I just can't resolve it and I don't know why. Can you help?

Comment: And yes I have, cuisines table populated from id 1 to 12

Comment: @rose instead of setting 
`$cuisines->random(rand(1, 12))->pluck('id')->toArray()`
you can try with `$cuisines->random(rand(1, $cuisine->count()))->pluck('id')->toArray()`

Comment: You requested 1 items, but there are only 0 items available. again similar error

Comment: You could run some troubleshooting and use `dd($cuisines);`  in your `UserCuisineTableSeeder`.
As well are you sure you want `$cuisines = UserCuisine::all();` and not `$cuisines = Cuisine::all();` ?

Comment: $cuisines returns empty array when I dump it under $cuisines = UserCuisine::all();

Comment: Yeah I got it.It works now. I changed protected $table = 'cuisine'; so now it returns full array. Anyway you helped me, thanks!

Comment: alrighty, don't forget to approve the answer if you are satisfied 

Answer (score 1):

Seems `user_cuisines` table does not exist, You have created `cuisine` not `user_cuisines`

Just put below code in `UserCuisine` model.

```
protected $table= 'user_cuisine';
```

I would recommend always use -m flag while creating a model to avoid these types of errors, for example.

```
php artisan make:model ModelName -m
```

Comment: With this now I get error   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_cuisine_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `user_cuisine` (`user_cuisine_id`, `user
_profile_id`) values (2, 1), (8, 1), (10, 1))

Comment: Hello @rose I have updated the table name that was my mistake, You need to put value in the fillable array to insert the records

Comment: In the user UserCuisine model fillable array shuld be like this protected $fillable = [
        'cuisine_id',
      'user_id'

    ];

Comment: Did that, and I get  You requested 1 items, but there are only 0 items available. it appears it is error somewhere in seeder around random but I cant seem to find it.